# Trying to make "next" and "previous" buttons that loop through navigation onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make "next" and "previous" buttons in my navigation. On click they should take me to the next/previous html file(web page).

code looks like this:

```js
const pages =
["home.html","about.html","skills.html","projects.html","contact.html"];

const currentUrl = window.location.href;
const i = pages.indexOf(currentUrl) 
const arrowUp = document.getElementById("up");
const arrowDown = document.getElementById("down");

function next(){
    i++;

    let goTo = pages[i];

    window.location = goTo;

    if(i===pages.length){
        i = 0;
    }
}

function prev(){
    i--;

    let goTo = pages[i];

    window.location = goTo;

    if(i=0){
        i = pages.length;
    }
}

arrowUp.addEventListener("click",next());

arrowDown.addEventListener("click",prev());
```

```html
<div id="arrows">
  <a href="#" id="up">
    <i class="far fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="down" class="mbot1">
    <i class="far fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Is link the problem, because of  href="#"? On click it just adds # on current url (like it would without js).

Comment: Your tests for `i === pages.length` needs to go before `let goTo = pages[i];`. Same problem with your test for what *should be* `i === 0`, and not `i = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `i` with `const`. It's not reassignable then. Use `var`or `let`

```
var i = pages.indexOf(currentUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code.

First, `i` is being declared with `const`, but needs to be declared with `let` or `var` if you want to set it again later. You're also checking if `i` equals 0 with `=`, which would set it, instead of the comparison operators `==` or `===`.

The other issue with your initial `i` value is that it could possibly be set at -1, if `currentUrl` isn't found in `pages`. Unless you're sure you'll always have `pages.indexOf(currentUrl) >= 0`, you should add a default/fallback value.

The start and end limits are also being checked after navigating. The issue is that if you're `home.html` (index 0), you're decrementing, navigating to index -1, and then setting `i = pages.length`. You should use an if/else statement to set `i`, or juts a ternary operator for short.

Lastly, `pages.length` set your pointer to one past the existing index. In your example, `pages` contains five items, but since an array index begins at 0, the last one is at `pages[4]`. `pages[5]` doesn't exist.

Try this code instead:

```
function next(){
    i = i === pages.length - 1 // if index at end
        ? 0                    // go to start
        : i + 1;               // else go next
    let goTo = pages[i];
    window.location = goTo;
}

function prev(){

    i = i === 0            // if index is at start
        ? pages.length - 1 // go to end
        : i - 1;           // else go back one
    let goTo = pages[i];
    window.location = goTo;
}
```